# Java JIT compiler register optimization

Tags: java, memory, jvm, jit, register-allocation

I am looking at some output native code from the Hotspot VM JIT compiler. The method that I am analyzing uses a lot of local variables. I had expected this to spillover the register allocation and make load/stores to and from memory. However, I do not see any load/store instructions in the native code. To this end, I have 2 related questions.

1. I have read that a Java VM has a stack-based architecture where instead of using registers as the scratchpad for calculations a stack is used. Thus, does the JIT compiler as well follow a stack-based model or a register-based one?
2. If the JIT is register-based, what does the JIT compiler do upon running out of registers? Does the JIT compiler perform some other technique to handle this case or is it the case that I am not seeing any load/store to and from memory simply because I do not have enough local variables?

Comment: 1) registers 2) that's hard to tell without knowing which CPU you have (we can guess) and how many local variables you have

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Hmm...Let's say there are 32 registers and over 50 local variables? Basically more variables than that can be stored in the registers. What can I expect to happen in this case? Should I see spillover to memory?

Comment: The assembler for the Java VM, Jasmin, is stack based. At the machine level there are still registers but I think the assembly code for java is a level of abstraction above that.

Comment: @BradySheehan I'm not sure what the link is between Jasmin and the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your question depends on the JVM and CPU architecture you're using.

I'll assume you're talking about hotspot.

> Thus, is the JIT compiler as well follow a stack-based model or a register-based one?

The bytecode operates on a stack, but that gets translated through several layers, the last one is register-based.

> If the JIT is register-based, what does the JIT compiler do upon running out of registers?

It may spill onto the stack or it may apply other optimizations to reduce register pressure, depending on their costs.

But it's also possible that previous optimization stages already produced code that fits into the available registers. Just because you use N local variables in your method doesn't mean you'll need N registers at any given time.

Take a look at the [OpenJDK wiki](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/HotSpot/Compiler), it has several pages on register allocation and also earlier optimization steps.

Comment: so just to make sure I have understood this correctly,  1) The bytecode interpreter uses a (virtual) stack but underneath this virtual stack, it is still just moving data in and out of registers? 2) By spill onto the stack, do you mean the memory? So I should theoretically see a bunch of load/store operations in my code if register pressure increases to a very high level right?

Comment: you asked about JIT compilers, not the interpreter.

Comment: Any idea of the second question on the effects of register pressure though? The part that really perplexes me is that there are no load/stores in the jit output code. So, i would just like to know if i should even expect to see any load/stores in the first place? Thanks for the OpenJDK link...will check it out

Comment: yes, eventually you will see mov/push/pop instructions

Comment: that is assuming you're on x86. different architectures, different names

Comment: HotSpot can also spill to xmm registers. push / pop isn't used for spilling on x86. Methods with constant stack depths are preferred.